# Sum each row and sum next row with 1 column offset to the right

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

Given above table, how can I sum each row, i.e. I will put the sum from A1 to G1 in A14, put sum from B2 to H2 in B14, and so on. so basically each row will add 7 columns, the next row will sum from 1 column to the right of column1 for 7 columns. what formula should i use? I can't just sum the whole row because there are actually more data in the right columns, but I omitted them for simplicity.

Comment: `BYROW()` or `BYCOL()` may work. Can you show your desired output?

Comment: I just need the output in anycell. E.g. in cell A14, B14, C14 and so on. So A14 contains sum of A1 to G1, B14 contains sum of B2 to H2, C14 contains sum of C3 to I3 and so on. Then i can drag the formula to apply for more rows if needed. So A14 should be 7, B14 should be 14, C14 should be 21 and so on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `BYROW()` to sum row wise data, then use `TOROW()` to through result horizontally.

```
=TOROW(BYROW(A1:I3,LAMBDA(x,SUM(x))))
```

[image]

Comment: however, my H and I, and all the subsequent columns might also contain values, I do not want to sum these. I only want to sum 7 columns from the starting column. i.e. row 1, sum A1 till G1 (7 cols). row 2, sum B2 till H2 (7 cols), even if columns after that contains values. and so on.

Answer (score 0):

`=LET(a,A1:I3,MMULT(INDEX(a,ROW(a),SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(a)-ROWS(a)+1,0)+ROW(a)),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(a)-ROWS(a)+1,,,0)))`
this will index the correct cells with a cell shift per row.

Or maybe simpler to follow:
`=LET(a,A1:I3,MAP(SEQUENCE(ROWS(a)),LAMBDA(b,SUM(INDEX(a,b,SEQUENCE(,7,b))))))`

And another approach:

```
=LET(range, A1:P4,
     cells, 7,
  SCAN( 0,         ROW(range)-1,
LAMBDA(calcresult,rowshift,
   SUM( DROP(TAKE(INDEX(range,rowshift+1,),,cells+rowshift),,rowshift)))))
```

[image]